# Reuse application in multiple applications by using component container

Tags: sapui5

The application I refer to in the component container isn't loaded in a specific case. Any idea what I am doing wrong or what I could do to solve my issue?

These are the steps I take for the problem to occur:

**Step 1: Open popover in worklist**
[image]

**Step 2: Navigate to detail by pressing 'a' in the worklist, after that open the popover in the detail** 
[image]

**Step 3: Navigate to the worklist by pressing the 'back-arrow' in the top left corner (see previous image), after that open the popover in the worklist again.**
[image]

I have 3 applications: worklist-app, detail-app, popover-app.

The popover-app is included in my worklist- and detail-app by using a component-container (the id of the popover is different in the worklist and detail app):

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <ResponsivePopover afterClose="destroyPopover" class="sapUiPopupWithPadding" id="popover--id1" placement="Left">
        <content>
            <core:ComponentContainer name="name.space.app" component="appname" propagateModel="true">
            </core:ComponentContainer>
        </content>
    </ResponsivePopover>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

In the Component.js of my worklist-app and detail-app I register my popover-app by using:

```
jQuery.sap.registerModulePath("name.space.app", "/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/appname");
```

In the onExit-method of my worklist-app and detail-app, I destroy the popover to prevent duplicate-id errors.

When I open the the popover in the worklist, the popover is opened correctly.
When I open the popover in the detail-app, the popover is opened correctly.

**When I am in the detail-app, I click the 'back-arrow' in the top left corner,**

[image]

** I navigate back to the worklist. If then I want to open the popover, the popover opens, but nothing is displayed inside.**

I would expect the popover would be visible as it was in step 1.

code to open popover:

```
if (!this._oPopover) {
            this._oPopover = sap.ui.xmlfragment("name.space.popover", this);
            this.getView().addDependent(this._oPopover);
            this._oPopover.setBusy(true);
}

this._oPopover.openBy(oEvent.getSource());
```

code to close popover:

```
if(this._oPopover) {
   this._oPopover.destroy();
}
```

I don't receive any error, so I have no clue how to debug what is actually going on.

I notice that I go in the App.controller of my popover-application, but after that he doesn't enter the onInit() of the Controller specified in my popover-view.

Someone ever had the same problem, or someone knows what is causing this behaviour or what I could do to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What is exactly the problem ? Is no content rendered in the Popover when you clicked back button and open it again? Do you need to execute the code which is in in the onInit mehtod ? Do you expect that the Component Container is not loaded again ? Please clarify what is exactly your problem.

Comment: @FrancescoIannazzo I've changed my question a bit.

Basically I expect that my popover is rendered again, same as in step 1 and obviously the onInit() function should be triggered again since the popover was destroyed in the onExit function of the worklist application.

Comment: How and where are you opening your popup? And what is written in the oninit of the popup?

Comment: @futu I added the code that I use to open and close (in my case destroy) my popup.
What is written in the oninit is irrelevant for my issue since it doesn't enter the onInit at my last step.

Comment: this._oPopover variable is not reset? The fragment is destroyed but the object is still there, so on second click it tries to open a destroyed fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've figured out why the application wasn't loaded any more. In the worklist (the endpoint when back-navigation was executed), I implemented an appstate in order to store previously set filters.

The appstate is stored via a key in the URL, because of this key, the `manifest` couldn't map the popover-application destination once it was tried to be opened.

I've solved it by adjusting the routing in the manifest of my popover application:

```
"routes": [
    {
        "pattern": ":?query:",
        "name": "popoverapp",
        "target": [
                "popoverapp"
        ]
    }
],
```

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced similar problems in the past and solved it by moving my onInit code to the onRouteMatched function of the default route method. This worked for me.

```
...
     onInit: function () {

            this.getRouter().getRoute("home").attachPatternMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this);


        },


        _onRouteMatched: function (oEvent) {
          //PUT your code here
        },
```

Comment: problem is that it doesn't even enters the onInit function of the popover app :(

Comment: Try it out, if it is an old instance of the component, the event listener is already registered. If not stop destroying the component, so it can be reused by the framework.

Comment: Sadly enough this didn't work either. I'm really out of ideas. Thanks for helping though

Answer (score 0):

On the first click this works fine, but on the second click, `!this._oPopover` is false and you try to open an invalid/destroyed fragment.

```
if (!this._oPopover) {
   //entered only on first click,
   //even after leaving app to a launchpad and navigating back in the app
   this._oPopover = sap.ui.xmlfragment("name.space.popover", this);
   this.getView().addDependent(this._oPopover);
   this._oPopover.setBusy(true);
}

this._oPopover.openBy(oEvent.getSource());
```

code to close popover:

```
if(this._oPopover) {
   this._oPopover.destroy();
   //Popover fragment is destroyed, but this._oPopover still holds an object
   //reset also variable here
  this._oPopover = undefined;
}
```

Normally you do not have to destroy the fragment and just close it and reopen it again because therefore you save it in `this._oPopover` so that it is not initialized again on every click.

Declaring `this._oPopover` as initial/undefined in onInit() of the controller opening the popup assures that when the view is initialized the fragment is also intitialized.

**EDIT** regarding your comment:

Normally a fragment does not have livecycle methods and is implented as [the following](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_uiaddon20/2.05/en-US/35/4f98ed2b514ba9960556333428d35e/content.htm?no_cache=true) in a kind of [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) design pattern.

If you have a whole own app wrapped around your popup fragment (thats what I understand), I am not sure how the lifecycle methods are handled in your case, when you only reference a fragment and do not work with views and navigation. In a view onBeforeRendering() is called always on **re-rendering** in contrary to onInit() that is only called once, see [this blog post](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/11/12/sapui5-controller-lifecycle-methods-explained/).

Nevertheless `this._oPopover = undefined;`, when destroying the fragment should fix your not very best practice approach?

Comment: true, destroying the popover is not best-practice, but it was the best way to make sure my 'onInit' function in the popover-application was always triggered again when the popover was opened. Unless you there is another way to always trigger the 'onInit' which I don't know of.

Comment: I'm currently working on some other issues at work which got a high priority, thanks for your help @futu, I'll try it asap and keep you posted :)

Comment: assigning undefined to this._oPopover doesn't solve the issue. It is very strange behaviour since In my detail app I got the exact same code and the popup is opening/closing and loading correct data all the time. 

I'm looking further into it.

Comment: so I've debugged a little further and noticed the following: when I click on the popover (after executing the steps mentioned in my post), I do enter the App.controller of my popover-application, but I don't get into the controller linked to the view it should display